# Assets: Unable to Upload Large Files to S3

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, s3

I'm trying to upload a 43MB .mp4 video file to S3 using Assets. The progress bar will run all the way to the end (it takes about a minute), then I'll get an alert that says "Undefined", and the console will show an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
(Internal Server Error) - https://mydomain.com/?folder=478&ACT=161&qqfile=my-video-file.mp4
```

- My php `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are both set to `256M`
- My `system/expressionengine/cache` directory and all sub-directories have 777 permissions
- EE 2.6.1
- Assets 2.1.4

Comment: Kristen, care to email us at the usual address with CP access, so we can get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple other PHP settings you might need to adjust to allow for large files to be uploaded. Try also increasing these two:

```
max_input_time 300  
max_execution_time 300
```

---

You may also peek at your php error log file to see if anything more specific is getting logged there.

Comment: I always forget to check the error logs! Looks like it's a FastCGI error, even though I *thought* I turned it off. *sigh*.

Comment: I'm happy to remind you:)